# Como gerar JAR e POM de projeto seguindo o layout do repositório do Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom

Possuo um projeto onde preciso gerar o jar e o pom seguindo o mesmo método com que o plugin **maven-install-plugin** gera dentro do repositório local, como no retorno que é dado ao contruir o projeto:

```
--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ projeto-java ---
Installing C:\Users\matheus\Java\Projeto-Java\target\Projeto-java-1.2.3.jar to C:\Users\matheus\.m2\repository\br\com\xxx\java\projeto-java\1.2.3\projeto-java-1.2.3.jar
Installing C:\Users\matheus\Java\Projeto-Java\pom.xml to C:\Users\matheus\.m2\repository\br\com\xxx\java\projeto-java\1.2.3\projeto-java-1.2.3.pom
```

Preciso que os arquivos **projeto-java-1.2.3.pom** e **projeto-java-1.2.3.jar** sejam colocados em diretório especifico, como posso mudar o diretório onde o plugin coloca ou tem outro plugin que faça isso?

Comment: Consegui achar uma solução baseado neste link... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879358/generating-jar-and-pom-file-following-the-maven-repository-layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879358/generating-jar-and-pom-file-following-the-maven-repository-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser feito definindo um profile e seu diretorio dentro do `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>novoProfile</id>
        <build>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/diretorioDesejado</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

E executando o comando utilizando o profile novo:

```
mvn install -PnovoProfile
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908061/3892340)